# NDK 11 linker is treating warnings as errors

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm trying to build a library with android ndk-11 and I'm getting a linker error:

`arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: treating warnings as errors`

I do not get this error if I use ndk-r10e.

Running ndk-build with V=1, I see that `-Wl,--fatal-warnings` is being passed to the linker. I've tried adding `LOCAL_LDFLAGS:=-Wl,--no-fatal-warnings` to my Android.mk file, and I can see in the linker output that it is in fact being passed to the linker, but it is passed *before* `-Wl,--fatal-warnings`, so it is being ignored.

The warnings are coming from a 3rd party library, so I can't just recompile it to fix the warnings (they are all 'relocation refers to discarded section' warnings). I've always seen these warnings and have never had any problems.

Does anyone know how to tell the ndk-11 linker *not* to treat warnings as errors?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I figured this out as I was writing it, so I thought I'd share the solution.

`<NDK_ROOT>/build/core` has a bunch of .mk files that are used when running ndk-build. Inside `build-binary.mk`, there are a few new (undocumented) checks for variables you can define. For this particular one, there is the following block:

```
# We enable fatal linker warnings by default.
# If LOCAL_DISABLE_FATAL_LINKER_WARNINGS is true, we don't enable this check.
ifneq ($(LOCAL_DISABLE_FATAL_LINKER_WARNINGS),true)
  LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -Wl,--fatal-warnings
endif
```

Adding `LOCAL_DISABLE_FATAL_LINKER_WARNINGS=true` to my .mk file made the error go away.

There are **lots** of other things defined in these files, so if you're getting weird build errors all of a sudden, take a look in there to see if something new has been enabled.

Comment: There you go. Your tip saved me. Thank you. +1

Comment: where to put this if I dont have .mk files ?

Comment: If you don't have .mk files in <NDK_ROOT>/build/core then you might not have the NDK installed properly. They still exist there as of NDK 25.0.8775105